# Keras TF can't get score up on MNIST

Tags: tensorflow, keras, mnist

I have a dataset of 2049 images (not alot I know) of Sign Language MNIST. I went through the default MNIST tutorial, just with these images instead. Is there a way to get my score up higher? Or is it just due to the low number of images? Thanks in advance! (Score is like less than a %)

https://gist.github.com/JLeavell/0600d18b249036fc2c17c34e1f78bfb1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are those real images? Actual hands from actual people? That is not easy at all and you need models way more powerful than MNIST examples.

I suggest you try using some of the well known image classification models avaiable in `keras.applications`, such as `vgg16`, `inception_v3` and some of the others [listed here](https://keras.io/applications/)

You will probably only create the top layers so the number of classes suits your possible classes.

Comment: Yeah they're actual images, but just of their hands. Here's a link to the dataset on Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/ardamavi/sign-language-digits-dataset . I did have to remove 3 images though, as they were taken with an iphone I think and had different dimensions.

Comment: So... difficult images.

Comment: Haha I guess. I didn't want to do the cookie cutter model so I found one as similiar (but different) as I could. I updated the gist in the post with a vgg16 net but it doesn't perform any different from what I can tell?

Comment: Are you sure you're normalizing your true outputs to be compatible with your last activation function?

Comment: As far as I know... yes?

Comment: Your code seems good overall... for how many epochs did you train?

Comment: Umm, 10 so far (just to see if it has any effect). Here's the output at epoch 10:1647/1647 [==============================] - 20s 12ms/step - loss: 14.0923 - acc: 0.1257 - val_loss: 16.1181 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171031/discussion-between-joey-leavell-and-daniel-moller).